# Remote machine accessing a deployed SSRS report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have created an SSRS report using the Business Intelligence reporting service of VS 2012 and I have also successfully deployed it on the web service url i.e. http://*computer name*/ReportServer, the deployment was successful. The main purpose of deployment is to enable the client to access these reports from their machine, and I really do not have much idea on how to proceed with that, what and how do I give permissions to the client and how does the client access the above url in order to view the reports? Please elaborate I was not able to find much online help on this and its my first venture in this domain. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Just change the "computer name" to "ip" address & then try. I am not sure if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Open Reporting Services Configuration manager from windows Start
Connect to your Report Server
basically Two ULR tabs are available there

Web Service URL
Report Manger URL

you want to go to Web service URL
assign Some virtual Directory then use that URL for client PCs.

if not work use IP address in place on Computer Name
for credentials use Service Account Tab in this Manager 
check Use another account
and what ever domain username is given here will be used for client to log in .

i Had same issue, i jst replaced computer name with deployed server IP address,

```
http://10.60.0.0/ReportServer
```